# function like imread() in R

Tags: r, image, matlab

Can somebody tell me whether there is a function like `imread` from matlab implemented in some package in R? I would like to read an image into R and then extract the rgb colors at specific positions from the picture.

`imreads` description mentions that the function `A = imread(filename, fmt)` will return A, a x-by-y-by-3 matrix where x and y are the number of pixels in the height and width dimensions, and the 3rd dimension contains the Red, Green and Blue values for each given pixel. This sounds like what I want to do.

Answer (score 3):

It depends whether you want to read png or jpeg file.

You can call the appropriate library.

Example for PNG,

```
library(png)
img <- readPNG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package="png"))
```

Example for JPEG

```
library(jpeg)
img <- readJPEG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.jpg", package="jpeg"))
```

Edit:

```
img <- readPNG("Rplot05.png")
```

Comment: oh okay...will that also create an array with the rgb values?

Comment: if i try the exampes with my files I get an error Error in readPNG(system.file("img", "Rplot05.png", package = "png")) : 
  unable to open but I am in the right directory

Comment: hello ..not really sure to understand the output...I get an array but what do the dimensions mean?

Comment: the dimensions for example when you read in matlab, 900x654x3 and in r it will be just 900*654*3 = 1765800.